# lock free algorithm version for for below algorithm

Tags: c++, lock-free

i am writing a network controlling feature so the algorithm is

1. read the current transfer rate
2. if it is less than the required transfer rate then proceed
   else
   sleep for some x seconds and go to step 1:
3. x is calculated based required transfer rate and current transfer rate.

can you please suggest how to make this algorithm thread safe

Comment: Where do threads come into play?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by thread safe. If by 'thread safe' you mean 'won't crash, deadlock, or livelock', then it's sufficient to simply:

```
x = atomic_read(current_transfer_rate);
memory_barrier();
if (x >= required_xfer_rate)
  sleep(f(x));
```

Note that it's important to capture the `current_transfer_rate` to a local variable *then issue a memory barrier* (exactly how to do this depends on your compiler). This will ensure the compiler doesn't read the variable more than once, potentially giving inconsistent results.

Of course, it's possible that some other process/thread might send some more data, increasing current_transfer_rate before you can transmit, resulting in current_transfer_rate exceeding limits. The only way to avoid this would be a central lock or queue for transmits, or a way to 'reserve' transfer capacity atomically.